# Create all Subset

Tags: scala, set, subset

Ok. I know. This is an exercise from Odersky's Course. But I'm so stuck with this for days.

define method to create all subset of a input set:

```
def combination(occ: List[(Char,Int)]) : List[List[(Char,Int)]]
```

Example: for input `List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))` obtain output:

```
List(
  List(),
  List(('a', 1)),
  List(('a', 2)),
  List(('b', 1)),
  List(('a', 1), ('b', 1)),
  List(('a', 2), ('b', 1)),
  List(('b', 2)),
  List(('a', 1), ('b', 2)),
  List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))
)
```

Perfect. For the moment I get two different things: all couples (1a) and list for single element (1b)

**1a** It works. it gives me all couples (tuples in general)

```
  def combinations(occurrences: List[(Char,Int)]) : List[List[(Char,Int)]] = {
    if (occurrences.isEmpty) List(Nil)
    else {
      val entry = occurrences.head;
      for (
           first <- (entry._2 to 1 by -1).toList;
           rest <- combinations(occurrences.tail))
        yield (entry._1, first) :: rest
    }
  }
```

Output `List(List((a,2), (b,2)), List((a,2), (b,1)), List((a,1), (b,2)), List((a,1), (b,1)))`

**1b**. It Works except I dont get empty list (well of course I dont)

```
  def combinations(occurrences: List[(Char,Int)]) : List[List[(Char,Int)]] = {
    for (entry <- occurrences;
         freq <- (entry._2 to 1 by -1).toList) yield List((entry._1,freq))

  }
```

Output `List(List((a,2)), List((a,1)), List((b,2)), List((b,1)))`

Now I'm totally stuck how to combine both.
Could you please help me into understand how can I achieve this?

Comment: I sorta hate to tell you this, because reading stuff like this when I took that class would drive me up a wall, but it can be done in a single statement, i.e. no `{}` needed after the `=`. It's a rather long single statement (I split it across 3 lines) involving recursion, a few items from the standard library, and a call to one other method in the file (hint: it's the next method in that file). I hope this isn't more harmful than helpful. Good luck.

Comment: Umh any advice just for methods of standard library?

Comment: I used `::` and `flatMap()` and removed redundancies with `distinct`. (Don't tell anyone I said so.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the efficiency, but you can take a look at this. This is a kind of coin change problem, i.e, given a total amount of money and all possible coins, how many ways there are to compose the change. One of the ideas *(from top to bottom approach)* is to come up with a recursive function which bifurcate whether you will take a specific kind of coins, which is what the inner combination function is doing here:

```
def combinations(occurrences: List[(Char,Int)]) : List[List[(Char,Int)]] = {
    // total number of coins
    val tot = occurrences.map(_._2).sum

    // add a pair to an existing combination
    def add(counter: List[(Char, Int)], element: (Char, Int)) = {
      val countMap = counter.toMap
      (countMap + (element._1 -> (countMap.getOrElse(element._1, 0) + element._2))).toList
    }

    // a recursive function to calculate all the combinations
    def combinations(occurs: List[(Char,Int)], n: Int): List[List[(Char,Int)]] = {
      if(n == 0) List(List())
      else if(occurs.isEmpty) List()
      else {
        val firstElement = if(occurs.head._2 == 1) List() else List((occurs.head._1, 1))
        // all the combinations if you take the first kind of coin
        val headComb = combinations(firstElement ++ occurs.tail, n - 1)

        // all the combinations if you don't take the first kind of coin
        val tailComb = combinations(occurs.tail, n)    

        // add the first coin pair to head combination and concatenate it with tail combination
        headComb.map(add(_, (occurs.head._1, 1))) ++ tailComb    
      }
    }

    // calculate the combinations for each amount separately
    (0 to tot).toList.flatMap(combinations(occurrences, _))
}


combinations(List())
// res49: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(List())

combinations(List(('a', 1)))
// res50: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(List(), List((a,1)))


combinations(List(('a', 1), ('b', 2)))
// res51: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(List(), List((a,1)), List((b,1)), List((b,1), (a,1)), List((b,2)), List((
// b,2), (a,1)))

combinations(List(('a', 2), ('b', 2)))
// res52: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(List(), List((a,1)), List((b,1)), List((a,2)), List((b,1), (a,1)), List((
// b,2)), List((b,1), (a,2)), List((b,2), (a,1)), List((b,2), (a,2)))
```

Comment: Well I'm happy it works, but I can't believe it has to be so hard to implement something like this :( Anyway, I really thank you, gonna try on my own with a different implementation from top to bottom approach

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a tip, but I can't give you a solution as **it would be coursera honor code violation**.

Notice that in your reasoning, it would be a good thing to consider `(_, 0)` as the empty set, and that all sets are containing the empty set ! You could think of a solution to filter them out.

```
List(('a', 2), ('b', 2)) <=> List(('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('a', 0), ('b', 0))
```

I hope it will help you ! Good luck !

Comment: Umh using Range (entry._2 to 1 by -1) automatically filters out if there is a (_,0) because generating-for, map to a None and exits

Comment: Yes but you don't wanna skip sets with 0's you want to add them without it

Answer (score 0):

To combine both of them, you should allow `first` to take 0 as a value, and then yield `rest`, concatenated to `(entry._1, first)` only if `first` is not equal to 0. That makes you output the subsets that do not contain all the couples. We are actually implementing the principle @alamit explained :

> ```
> List(('a', 2), ('b', 2)) <=> List(('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('a', 0), ('b', 0))
> ```

Thus, `first` would now be written as :

```
first <- (entry._2 to 0 by -1).toList;
```

and you would yield the following :

```
yield if first != 0 then (entry._1, first) :: rest else rest
```